# databinding propertygrid to property shows correctly in XAML preview engine but fails on runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, prism, propertygrid

First off, I am using the MVVM pattern with the Prism libraries. My application shell has two Regions: a main diagram region containing diagram shapes and items, and an auxiliary region as a kind of frame on the left side. So far so good: the regionmanager loads the regions correctly into my shell.

My goal is to have a PropertyGrid in the auxiliary region show certain properties of a selected diagram item which is inside a canvas inside a listbox within the main diagram region. One of the properties of a diagram item is the string "Token". I am very close to making it work, and indeed the XAML preview engine shows all the properties in the propertygrid when I hardcode my diagram item to be the SelectedItem my propertyGrid binds to, but once I run the program the propertyrgid remains empty. In other words, the XAML preview engine shows the desired result, but once I run the program, the result isn't the same.

Whan can be going wrong then?

My PropertyGrid's XAML:

```
        <local:PropertyGrid AutomaticlyExpandObjects="False"  
                         Width="200" 
                         Margin="5"
                         x:Name="propertyGrid" 
                         ShowDescription="False" 
                         ShowPreview="False"
                         Instance="{Binding Path=SelectedItem}">
        </local:PropertyGrid>
```

Property code within my PropertyGrid's DataContext:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The state that is currently selected.
    /// </summary>
    public StateViewModel SelectedItem
    {
        get
        {
            return m_selectedItem;
        }
        set
        {
            if (m_selectedItem == value)
                return;

            m_selectedItem = value;

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }
```

As I said, and what's most weird to me is the XAML preview engine correctly shows the SelectedItems properties like I would love them to be, but once I run the program, the propertygrid remains empty.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: guess: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true

Comment: i put that line in my LisBox, but still the same...

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is only used when you take advantage of the binding syntax for the current selected item in a collection(view) like {Binding MyListOfItems/}

Answer (score 0):

Most-likely it's a binding issue. Your DataContext might not be what you expect or the INotifyPropertyChanged events for your property might not be firing like you think they should.

Bea Stollnitz has a great article on the subject: http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=52

In particular, this nugget and observing the output window will tell you a lot:

> ```
> <Window …
> xmlns:diagnostics="clr-namespace:System.Diagnostics;assembly=WindowsBase"
> />
> <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Caption, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}" … />
> ```

Comment: How can I use this code snippet? Should I create a new dedicated  window for this debugging info to show? Do I understand this correctly?

Comment: I get the following in my Output: "System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SelectedItem' property not found on 'object' ''PropertyGrid' (Name='propertyGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedItem; DataItem='PropertyGrid' (Name='propertyGrid'); target element is 'PropertyGrid' (Name='propertyGrid'); target property is 'Instance' (type 'Object')".

Comment: Based on this error, your DataContext is the property grid. Is this what you expected?

Comment: My propertyGrid's Datacontext should be a "WorkfloViewModel" whose corresponding view is placed in another region. That's what I specified. in the XAML. Now, I believe my desired DataContext here is somehow inaccessible in the scope of the region, since it is not part of the same branch in the visual/logic tree? I am currently reading up on how to resolve views and register them in regions so that there can be binding between them, using DataContext. I thought this would be a frequent scenario: bind a PropertyGrid in RegionA to some ViewModel in RegionB. But there is something I'm overlooking

Comment: @Sebastian Schavoir: Yeah... something is definitely not right... you don't have a DataContext. DataContext flows into inner controls from outer controls as long as nothing overrides it. You can use WPF Inspector to look at your DataContext at each control to find where it breaks in the hierarchy. http://www.wpftutorial.net/Inspector.html